# Best way how save nodes of graph

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve how save nodes of graph. Every node can have more ancestors and more descendants. Now I have this struct:

```
struct Node
{
  int m_Value; 
  int m_Index; // end Node in m_Nodes
  int m_Length; // actual size of m_Nodes and m_Prev (for realloc)
  Node* m_Nodes; // dynamic array (descendants)
  Node* m_Prev; // dynamic array (ancestors)
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way. The graph can look like this:

```
  1
2   3
  4

Edges: [1,2], [1,3], [2,4], [3,4], [4,1]
```

Thank you for your opinions.

Comment: *int m_Length; // actual size of m_Nodes and m_Prev (for realloc)*  -- You don't need this if you used container classes such as `std::vector` that know their own sizes.

Comment: Is your graph a Directed Acyclic Graph or a general graph? To avoid memory leaks, you may need to record the nodes in another data structure.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I know. I wan to implement without it. My mistake that I I had not noticed it.

Comment: @Franck The graph can by cyclic.

Comment: Your implementation is reasonable. So you need a graph structure with a container that owns the nodes to avoid the memory leaks. If the edges carry some information, you can introduce them by replacing `Node* m_Nodes` with `Edge* m_ForwardEdges`.

Comment: @Franck Thank you. It sounds better then my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save edge and point separately.And you need a function to get all edge of one point. so the memory malloc & free operation me be less